How to extract a rare sat from a Bitcoin wallet
Please I need help. I helped receive some money an amount of 77$ on a phantom wallet and when I tried to withdraw by sending to another wallet, it say zero available bitcoin to send and shows it’s locked due to a rare sat. They keep asking me to use utxo to extract the sat so I can send out my bitcoin but I can’t seem to get through it and now I’m into an unplanned debt. Crypto shouldn’t be this complicated
